# PHP MYSQL set AUTO INCREMENT to MAX + 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, auto-increment

I have a PHP file that inserts data from a CSV file into the MYSQL DB using the LOAD DATA INFILE sql function.

If the CSV data is a duplicate it is not inserted because of the DB table indexing rules (unique).

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 
       '" . $makes_file . "' IGNORE 
       INTO TABLE make 
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (make, img_url)";

$link->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

For some reason the Auto Increment of the table is not correct from this process.

So I have used the following code to correct this.

```
$get_max = $link->query("SELECT max(id) as max FROM `make` LIMIT 1");
while ($r = $get_max->fetch_assoc()) {
    $link->query("ALTER TABLE  `make` AUTO_INCREMENT = " . ($r['max'] + 1)) or 
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}
```

So if anybody knows:

1. Why the Auto Increment is incorrect from the LOAD DATA sql 
   or
2. If there is a 'prettier' way to set the auto increment to the max(id) +1

Thanks

Comment: you can use trigger to set `AUTO_INCREMENT` value when delete row

Answer (score 5):

For MyISAM tables you can just set AUTO_INCREMENT to 0 and MySQL will use the current maximum value plus one.

```
$link->query('ALTER TABLE make AUTO_INCREMENT = 0');
```

[From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to any that
>   have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal 
>   to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value 
>   is reset to the current maximum plus one.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is about a  *prettier way to set the auto increment to the max(id) +1*, You can do this with one Query only :

```
$link->query("ALTER TABLE  `make` AUTO_INCREMENT = ( SELECT max(id)+1 FROM `make` LIMIT 1 )" );
```

But your first solution should work if `AUTO_INCREMENT` is `unique` , check your database sheme

Comment: do you agree that he shouldn't need to?

Comment: I agree , it should auto-increment if AUTO_INCREMENT is unique as he said , my answer is about If there is a 'prettier' way to set the auto increment to the max(id) +1

Comment: on INNODB this gives me an unspecified (vague) syntax error (#1064): "something is wrong" with the syntax, quoting the whole subquery. I need this because the AI counter goes completely wild after daily ON DUPLICATE KEY where most records already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check your last id in your database manually and get it

Then insert new record and set id to
Your last id plus say 3 or 4

Example

If your last taken id is 5000
Insert new record and set id  to 5003
Then auto increment will works again from 5003.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).